# Inserting data into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, time-limit-exceeded

My code currently doesn't insert data into MySQL fast enough. However I don't know how to measure the current speed.

```
def insert():
      mycursor = mydb.cursor()
      plik = input(":::")
      agefile = open("C:/Users/juczi/Desktop/New Folder/" + plik, "r")
      sql = "INSERT INTO wyciek (nick, ip) VALUES (%s, %s)"
      for row in agefile:
            mydb.commit()
            data = row.split(':')
            val = (data[0].replace("\n",""), data[1].replace("\n", ""))
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
      agefile.close()
```

Comment: "I was wondering if there is any faster way ..." why? Is your code currently not fast enough, or do you just want speed for speed's sake?

Comment: The code is not fast enough, i need it to be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to insert data in bulk to Mysql the best would be to use [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) instead of doing it in a loop on top of an interpreted language, which is inevitably slower. However there is less flexibility if you need to transform data but that shouldn't be a problem in your case. All you're doing is get rid of carriage return. This is a plain delimited file without heavy transformation.

The `mydb.commit()` is misplaced. It should be called *after* running an insert/update. On the first iteration there is nothing to be committed.
But this is not efficient. I suggest that you take full advantage of **transactions**. Start a transaction at the beginning, do your loop and commit at the end. In case of error, you roll back. The added benefit is **data integrity**. If an error occurs, the data already inserted is "undone" so you don't end up with garbage due to a partial import of data.

Schema:

```
try:
    conn.autocommit = False

    # insert loop..

    # Commit your changes
    conn.commit()

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to update record to database rollback: {}".format(error))
    # reverting changes because of exception
    conn.rollback()
```

See for example: [Use Commit and Rollback to Manage MySQL Transactions in Python](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-transaction-management-using-commit-rollback/)

This alone should improve performance but you have to test it to measure the gain.

Not performance-related, but you can also use a **context manager** whenever possible, for instance when opening/writing to a file. So:

```
agefile = open("C:/Users/juczi/Desktop/New Folder/" + plik, "r")
```

becomes:

```
with open("C:/Users/juczi/Desktop/New Folder/" + plik, "r") as agefile:
   # do something
```

and you don't have to bother closing the file, this is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Build a 'batch' `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO wyciek (nick, ip) VALUES (12, 34), (234, 456), ...
```

Then execute it.  If your columns are `VARCHAR` instead of `INT`, be sure to put quotes around each value.

For 100 rows, this will run about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`.

(And that is aside from having the `COMMIT` inside the loop!)

Plan B:

If your data comes from a file, consider using `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`.  It may be even faster than plan A.

If you data is not *already* in a file, building the file to do `LOAD` *may* be slower than Plan A.